# MySQL query assignment Error

Tags: mysql, sql

When I following query

```
Select
case
        when (@nume=Start_Date)  then  null        
        when (@nume!=Start_Date) then @num
End,
case
        when (@nume=Start_Date and @nume:=End_Date)  then  null 
        when (@nume!=Start_Date) then @nume
End,
case
        when (@nume!=Start_Date and @nume:=End_Date and @num:=Start_Date)  then  @nume 
End
from P,(Select @num:=(Select Start_Date from P order by Start_Date desc Limit 1),@nume:=(Select End_Date from P order by Start_Date desc Limit 1 )) as A
;
```

In the next turn it assigns integer 1 value to @nume, rather than Date as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"as it is supposed to".  Hmmm, the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html) explicitly states:

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> ```
> SET @a = @a + 1;
> ```
>
> For other statements, such as `SELECT`, you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined.

Your interpretation of what your code is supposed to do is in direct contradiction to the documentation.  I would suggest that you ask another question, describing the problem you are trying to solve, and including sample data and desired results.